# Device logs not appearing in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have some crash logs which I am able to see in the iPad when I go to Settings->About->Diagnostics & Usage ->Diagnostics & Usage Data. But when I connect my iPad to the my computer and click Xcode->Window->Organizer->My Device Name, I am not able to see the logs at all. What might have been the issue? Any idea.

Comment: Restart Device and Xcode.

Comment: still not able to do it...

Comment: Did you delete the logs...

Comment: no.. it is appearing in my iPad....

Comment: A little checklist here...a) is device enabled for dev? b) do all the options appear under MyDeviceName [Applications, Console, Profiles, Device Logs]? c) Are you looking for logs under Console or Device Logs, d) try resymbolicating the logs?

Comment: a=true,b=true,c=true,d=Device Logs are the answers to your question...

Comment: @iProgrammed, I did delete the logs and since then I do not see new ones. Do you know what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better Method to take device logs:

```
~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<your iPhone’s name>/
```

Comment: This folder is old and out of date and doesn't have the latest logs.  When is this folder sycned?

Comment: this is not actually an answer to the original question, i could use an answer to that one...

Comment: @PokerIncome.com I guess you need to do a itunes synch.

Comment: Is it same for Xcode 6.4 also? am not able to see any crash logs.

Answer (score 2):

The device logs are now contained in SQLite databases in this folder:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS Device Logs
```

Clear that out and take control of your CPU from Xcode again! Once its cleared out then maybe you'll get it to show the one you want if to perform the crash again.